# css - target two elements in a div without repeating parent class

Tags: css

For example, I've this -

```
<div class="epindiv"><p>Enter No. of Epins:</p> <input size="2" type="text" /> <div class="clear-both"></div></div>
```

I want to target `<p>` tag and `<input/>` tag. but i don't wanna write like this -

`.epindiv p, .epindiv input`

Is there a more efficient way of writing this without repeating parent class?

Comment: Give them ID's and use that

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper That wouldn't be the best way to go, classes seem more like it. Has anyone ever heard of [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: oh yeah SASS why didn't I taught of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case you can use `.epindiv *:not(:last-child)`

```css
.epindiv *:not(:last-child) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="epindiv">
  <p>Enter No. of Epins:</p>
  <input size="2" type="text" />
  <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything like first-child, second-child, third-child, n-th-child as well?

Comment: @SevenHong you mean css selector?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - this doesn't work for float. If i want to use float:left for first two, it doesn't work. All of them floats.

Comment: @SagarRaj I think there was a small mistake I forgot to add `:` with `last-child`. Please try with updated answer.